# I get an error during database insertion

Tags: android

when im going to insert the the data in database i found the following errors
please give me solution

```
07-26 12:24:38.275: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-26 12:24:45.445: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-26 12:24:46.705: ERROR/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
07-26 12:24:46.705: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-26 12:24:46.705: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-26 12:24:46.757: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-26 12:24:52.576: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-26 12:24:52.576: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58): Failure starting core service
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-26 12:24:52.727: ERROR/System(58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
07-26 12:24:53.727: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-26 12:24:53.737: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-26 12:24:53.737: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-26 12:24:53.737: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-26 12:24:53.746: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-26 12:24:56.527: ERROR/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-26 12:24:57.955: ERROR/logwrapper(142): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 12:24:58.026: ERROR/logwrapper(144): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 12:24:58.096: ERROR/logwrapper(146): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 12:25:10.246: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dataApplication/com.dataApplication.Edit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.dataApplication.Edit.onCreate(Edit.java:87)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     ... 11 more
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dataApplication/com.dataApplication.Edit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.dataApplication.Edit.onCreate(Edit.java:87)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-26 12:26:54.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the error you got is:

```
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:25:41.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.dataApplication.Edit.onCreate(Edit.java:87)
```

You are accessing a object that is not existing on line 87 in your Edit class.